# Create relationship between nodes in neo4j

Tags: neo4j

In Neo4j, I want to create relationship between nodes where both the nodes are related with a common node.

For Example, I have three nodes where 2 student nodes and a teacher node. I already have relation between student and teacher. Now I want to create a third relationship between student to student where both the students are already related to the same teacher.
[image]

In the above image T1 and T2 are teacher nodes. S1, S2, S3 and S4 are student nodes. The relationships which are in blue is already created. now I want to create the relationships which are given in yellow.

Please help. Thanks in Advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1) If simple:

```
// Choose a pair of students with common teacher
MATCH p = (S1:Student)-[:has_teacher]->(T:Teacher)<-[:has_teacher]-(S2:Student)
    // Without [:common_teacher] relationships
    WHERE NOT (S1)-[:common_teacher]-(S2)
// And create relationships
CREATE (S1)-[r1:common_teacher]->(S2)
CREATE (S2)-[r2:common_teacher]->(S1)
```

2) If on the other:

You do not need to create additional relationships between the students, because they are already bound by a common teacher.